# Libgdx load a screen while drawing another screen

Tags: java, libgdx

Is it possible to render a screen (like a loading bar) while creating another screen and then set this screen as the main screen ?

Something like this :

```
private void update() {
    if(!myscreenIsLoaded) {
        drawLoadingBar();
    } else {
        game.setScreen(myScreen);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

This is the complete answer to your yes/no question. To see how to do so, take a look at this as an example: https://github.com/pedja1/SMC-Android/blob/master/core/src/rs/pedjaapps/smc/screen/LoadingScreen.java